# Is it possible to use both @queryParam and @Context in single REST call

Tags: rest

Is it possible to use both `@queryParam` and `@Context` in single REST call

I have a requirement to get data for two different operation. So i am thinking to use `@queryParam` for one and another from `@Context`.

Comment: of course, it is possible...you just need to implement a solution

Comment: @Leo, Could you please provide some pointer on how to achieve it.

Comment: a brand-new GET operation that takes 2 query string parameters and serves the response